# Group same amounts together but find differing amounts in a different column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create a query that finds one or more of the same amount where there is at least two different amounts in a different column. See below example for what the output should look like:

```
Name total_amount  amount
a1      1000         200
a1      1000         200
a1      1000          0
a1      1000         100
a2      3400         300
a2      3400         100
a2      3400         300
a3      5000         500
a3      5000          0
a3      5000         500
a3      5000         200
```

The numbers can be either negative or positive.
I have tried:

```
Select name, total_amount, amount 
from table1
where total_amount IN (Select total_amount from table1 where amount IN (Select distinct amount from table1 group by amount) 
group by total_amount 
having count(*) > 1)
order by total_amount
```

Any suggestions welcomed, thanks in advance!

Comment: What's your expect result?

Comment: The table above the query I have provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `exists` :

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where exists (select 1 
              from table1 t2 
              where t2.total_amount = t1.total_amount and t1.amount <> t2.amount
             );
```